# Assembly LoadEffectiveAddress (LEA) is not working

Tags: assembly, masm

I write simple windows x64 applicaiton on assembler (create window and show it).
But when I init WNDCLASSEX structure, I`ve got incorrect pointer to WndProc function.

```
    invoke WndProc1, 0,0,0,0 ; for testing purposes. Its fails here, of course

    mov wc.cbSize,         sizeof WNDCLASSEX
    mov wc.style,          CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW 
                            ; or CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW
    ; mov rbx, OFFSET WndProc1
    lea rbx, [WndProc1]
    mov wc.lpfnWndProc,    rbx
```

I view my code in dissasembler from studio and got strange result:

```
    invoke WndProc1, 0,0,0,0
00007FF6AB941066  xor         ecx,ecx  
00007FF6AB941068  xor         edx,edx  
00007FF6AB94106A  xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF6AB94106D  xor         r9d,r9d  
00007FF6AB941070  call        WndProc1 (07FF6AB9411F5h)  

    mov wc.cbSize,         sizeof WNDCLASSEX
00007FF6AB941075  mov         dword ptr [wc (07FF6AB944472h)],50h  
    mov wc.style,          CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW 
00007FF6AB94107F  mov         dword ptr [wc+4h (07FF6AB944476h)],3  
                            ; or CS_BYTEALIGNWINDOW
    ; mov rbx, OFFSET WndProc1
    lea rbx, [WndProc1]
00007FF6AB941089  lea         rbx,[WndProc1 (07FF6AB941014h)]  
    mov wc.lpfnWndProc,    rbx
```

Call to function: **call        WndProc1 (07FF6AB9411F5h)**

Get function pointer with LEA or mov: **lea         rbx,[WndProc1 (07FF6AB941014h)]**

I try to use `mov rbx, OFFSET WndProc1` - not working same way.

I add `testptr dq 0` before WndProc1 in code and `lea rbx, [testptr+8]` got right result.

What I doing wrong?

I use visual studio 2022, ml64 and headers from masm64.

Comment: Show how `WndProc1` is defined along with the machine code for the instructions. Also make sure it's not defined multiple times.  Check symbol table. This is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I view 'incorrect' address with debugger and get this:

```
00007FF61115100A  jmp         mousemove (07FF61115120Bh)  
00007FF61115100F  jmp         timer (07FF6111511FDh)  
00007FF611151014  jmp         WndProc1 (07FF61115121Fh)  
00007FF611151019  jmp         main (07FF611151050h)
```

Its a jump table to my function!